# What javascript apis can I use to develop a web mapping application with image (like floor plan)?

Tags: javascript

I would like to develop a indoor web mapping application like google map (but the background is not a world wide map, is a static images like the bulidings' floor plan), which javascript apis that will suitable for me to use? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Panoroma Pro application. Also, It has html export option.

Answer (score 0):

Google maps API allow you to fix the map. So it look like static image.